# Types and functions with same name in Python 3.X?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

As I understand there are no declaration types in Python. When you need an integer or list you would do:

```
integer = 5
list_of_integers = [0, 1, 2]
```

This [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) to the documentation tells me that `int` in Python is a built-in function.

I'm aware of functions such as `str()` and `int()` to convert an integer to string and vice-versa.

But I have never seen a use of `int` as a type with dot notation E.g. *int.[function_name]*

How come it can be both a type and a function with the same name? Are there other types such as `float`, `double`, and etc. which can be used with dot notation and as well as a function?

Comment: There are actually some methods that you can call on integers, i.e. `(15).bit_length()` returns `4`. The parentheses are needed for the parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` and `str` are *classes*. As with any class in Python, calling it gives you an instance. And as with any instance, you certainly can call methods on it. `int` doesn't have that many user-callable methods, but `str` certainly does: some of the common ones include `strip`, `split`, `upper`, etc.

```
>>> x = str()
>>> x.upper()
''
```

**Edit**

It's still a class. You can do exactly the same with any class, even ones you define yourself:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def bar(self):
...     print self.baz
...
>>> f=Foo()
>>> f.baz = 'quux'
>>> f.bar()
quux
>>> Foo.bar(f)
quux
```

The last operation here is exactly the same idea as calling `str.upper(x)`

Comment: ints do have user accessible attributes, but they're not always very useful and mostly there so that `int` fits in its proper place in [the numeric tower](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/numbers.html#the-numeric-tower). eg, because integers are rational, they have a numerator and denominator; because they're complex, they have real and imaginary parts. They also have the `conjugate()` method, again a complex thing. More usefully but less obviously, all comparison and arithmetic operators and the functions round, divmod, floor, ceil and trunc call `__`-methods.

Comment: Sure, that's why I said "not that many", not "none". But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It is possible to write `str.upper(x)` Is `str` an object of type `str` or is it still a class here?

Answer (score 0):

int and str aren't functions.
They are basically data types which in python are actually classes containing different functions of their own.
That's why you can convert an integer to a string using the str(int) method but you can't do the same with int(string) to convert a string to an integer.
And as these are classes one can say that there are different functions (methods) in the class which are in turn use with the dot notation.